# How to create video streaming for Local Network using C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, stream, aforge

I have been working on the solution to develop video streaming services using C#.  In my case I need to implement videostream to local network via Ethernet. I try use AForge.NET Framework and AForge.FFmpeg.dll namespace. I convert my images to mp4 video.

My code for converting images to video file

```
   using (var vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
        {
            // Create file
            vFWriter.Open("VideoMaker.avi", width, height, framRate, VideoCodec.MPEG4);

            foreach (var imageEntity in lstImg)
            {
                //var bmp = ToBitmap(ImageToByteArray(lstImg));
                var bmp = new Bitmap(imageEntity);
                vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bmp);
            }

            Debug.WriteLine($"Images quantity: {lstImg.Count}");
            vFWriter.Close();
        }
```

So I think I need to use VideoFileReader class to read my video.

```
  using (var fileReader = new VideoFileReader())
        {
            fileReader.Open("VideoMaker.avi");

            Debug.WriteLine("width:  " + fileReader.Width);
            Debug.WriteLine("height: " + fileReader.Height);
            Debug.WriteLine("fps:    " + fileReader.FrameRate);
            Debug.WriteLine("codec:  " + fileReader.CodecName);
         }
```

But I can't find any solution to create stream.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to transcode on the fly, or that you just want to serve the video in a similar way to YouTube, Vimeo, etc.?

Comment: On the fly. All files will be stored in the database or on the drive.